# spark scala json string to json object customed

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I have Dataframe with json string column col1 such that this string is built of Maps where most of Maps have same schema but it might be that one of the Maps has got different schema than the others.

How to parse such json string?

1. Should I explode the json string first into separate rows
2. Having separate rows should I cast json string to json object using schema condition (how to recognize which map has which schema?)

How to split such json string into separate rows?

e.g.

this is sample value:

```
{"protocol":"xxx","start-time":111,"duration":0, "foo":1}
{"protocol":"xxx","start-time":111,"duration":0, "foo":1}
{"protocol":"xxx","start-time":111,"foo":1}
{"protocol":"xxx","start-time":111,"duration":0, "foo":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You only explode when you have an array of objects. In your case, you can not do that because you simply have many rows of objects as string (from what I am understanding).
2. You can use the union of all your JSON schemas, and the attributes that don't exist on specific rows, will become null.

A solution to your input (which I assume is what you have):

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|col1                                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|{"protocol":"xxx","start-time":111,"duration":0, "foo":1}|
|{"protocol":"xxx","start-time":111,"duration":0, "foo":1}|
|{"protocol":"xxx","start-time":111,"foo":1}              |
|{"protocol":"xxx","start-time":111,"duration":0, "foo":1}|
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

With these following transformations:

```
ds = ds
  .withColumn("col1",
    expr("from_json(col1, 'STRUCT<`duration`: BIGINT, `foo`: BIGINT, `protocol`: STRING, `start-time`: BIGINT>')")
  )
  .withColumn("protocol", col("col1.protocol"))
  .withColumn("start-time", col("col1.start-time"))
  .withColumn("duration", col("col1.duration"))
  .withColumn("foo", col("col1.foo"))
```

Will give you these result:

```
+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+---+
|col1               |protocol|start-time|duration|foo|
+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+---+
|{0, 1, xxx, 111}   |xxx     |111       |0       |1  |
|{0, 1, xxx, 111}   |xxx     |111       |0       |1  |
|{null, 1, xxx, 111}|xxx     |111       |null    |1  |
|{0, 1, xxx, 111}   |xxx     |111       |0       |1  |
+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+---+
```

Good luck!

Comment: the challenge is you do not know the schema so you can not use struct and will from_json solve it?

Comment: So you are trying to 'parse' to columns a schema that you do not know the format of?

Comment: correct. I am trying to parse json string not knowing it schema so I can extract single specific field from it knowing it shall be there.